# How can I change my recyclerView items order?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I would like to sort my items in order to put at the beginning chosen elements, I created a small piece of code allowing it which works rather well, but when I update my array in the adapter, the recyclerview is unchanged. I tried to do it with an update function in my adapter, and with the debugger, I see that the passed array is modified but nothing in the view... I also tried to send my array when creating the adapter but nothing changes. More weird, because I also have a filter by alphabetical order which works well.... Anyone have an idea? Thanks

Here's is my sort code which work, I tested it with the debugger:

```
    for (i in 0 until folders.size) {
        val isRead: String? = prefNewDir.getString(folders[i].absolutePath, null)

        if (isRead != null) { 
            println("before : "+folders[i] + "et i :" + i)

            val old= folders[i]
            folders.removeAt(i)
            folders.add(0, old)

            println("after : "+folders[i] + "et i :" + i)
        }
    }
```

Here my update method in my adapter:

```
fun updateData(data: MutableList<File>) {
    println("update before : "+items[0])
    items = data
    println("update after : "+items[0])

    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Here's my adapter code:

```kotlin
class DirAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var items: MutableList<File>,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DirAdapter.DirViewHolder>() {

    private val prefNewDir: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("new_files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)


    class DirViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val Dir_name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.file_name)
        val DirIsRead = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.file_new)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType : Int):DirViewHolder{

        val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)                         //Mode dossier
            .inflate(R.layout.folder_element, parent, false)

        return DirViewHolder(view)
    }

    fun updateData(data: MutableList<File>) {
        println("update data : "+items[0])
        items = data
        println("update data : "+items[0])

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DirViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentDir = items[position]
        holder.Dir_name.text = currentDir.name

        val isRead: String? = prefNewDir.getString(currentDir.absolutePath, null)         // On recupere si oui ou non le fichier est lu

        if (isRead!=null) {
            holder.DirIsRead.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else
            holder.DirIsRead.visibility = View.GONE


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, FilesActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("path",currentDir.absolutePath)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {


            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(context, it)
            if (isRead != null) {                     //Popup seulement sur un element
                popupMenu.menu.add("Marquer comme lu")
            }
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                if (it.title == "Marquer comme lu") {
                    putFolderAsRead(currentDir)
                    holder.DirIsRead.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                true

            }
            popupMenu.show()

            true
        }

    }

    private fun putFolderAsRead(folder: File) {

        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefNewDir.edit()
        editor.remove(folder.absolutePath)

        //Dossier courant
        val folderList = folder.listFiles()

        for (dListItem in folderList) {
            if(dListItem.isDirectory)           //Si un dossier est present on reboucle dessus
                putFolderAsRead(dListItem)
            editor.remove(dListItem.absolutePath)
            println(dListItem.absolutePath + " Marque comme lu !")
        }
        editor.apply()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size
}
```

Comment: Is your adapter's `getView()` using `items`?

Comment: Yes sorry that's right. I just noticed that even when I sort by last modification, the order in the adapter is not moved.. Even more strange

Comment: Could you post more (or all) of your adapter code? I believe the issue lies somewhere in that class.

Comment: I have added it, thank you for addressing my concern

Comment: To confirm, your print statements/debugging in `updateData` show what you expect, but the rendered list is not reflecting the change?

Comment: Yes absolutely,

Comment: Is your update happening on a different thread by chance? That could be a possible cause.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, I instanciate my adapter with the same array just above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244577/discussion-between-dan-harms-and-bam-bou).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all for storing data in shared preferences, I'd prefer you to use my library [here](https://github.com/sambhav2358/TinyDB). You can refer the docs to see how it works. Also, I'd prefer you to use a `data class` instead of the File class. That won't give you what you want. Since, you already show the files without sort, you just need some modifications:

1. Make a data class like this:

   ```kotlin
   data class MyFile(var file: File, var isNew: Boolean = false)
   ```
2. Now, the sorting part will be like this:

   ```kotlin
   var folders = getFolders(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
   for (i in 0 until folders.size) {
      val isRead: String? = prefNewDir.getString(folders[i].absolutePath, null)

      folders.get(i).isNew = if(isRead == null) false else true
   }
   ```
3. Now also, you might want to get the folder without sorting and you might be a bit confused, so, here is the code for getting the folders

   ```kotlin
   fun getFolders(location:File) : ArrayList<MyFile>(){
      val files = location.listFile()
      var foldersList = ArrayList<MyFile>()
      for (file in files) {
         if(file.isDirectory){ foldersList.add(MyFile(file)) }
      } 
   }
   ```

This will do the task for you.

Comment: I knew for a long time that a myFile class would have been useful but I was always lazy to take the step haha anyway it works now thanks I will also look for the database